# Lib to generate SiteMap in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitemap

Is there a lib i can use in C# to generate a sitemap for my asp.net website?

I am looking for something that i can insert data into and it will tell me if the generated sitemap has reach its limit or if the file size has reach it limit. Then allows me to save it as a file

Comment: Thanks for selecting my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK theres no libs for what you want to do (judging by your comments). You can however use .net xml wrapped into your own class to generate it. Its shouldnt be difficult. You also should take account of ascii characters and 4 byte breaks (2 for \r and 2 for \n).

Answer (score 5):

Here you can check my code to generate Sitemap.xml based on already prepared collection of SiteMapUrl objects:

```
            XNamespace ns = XNamespace.Get("http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9");
        XElement urlset = null;
        XDocument siteMapDocument = new XDocument(urlset = new XElement(ns + "urlset"));
        foreach (var links in siteMap.SiteMapUrls)
        {
            urlset.Add(new XElement
            (ns + "url",
            new XElement(ns + "loc",links.Location),
            new XElement(ns + "lastmod", DateTime.Now),
            new XElement(ns + "changefreq", Enum.GetName(typeof(SiteMapUrlChangeFreqs), links.ChangeFreq)),
            new XElement(ns + "priority", "0.2")
            ));
        }

        siteMapDocument.Save(String.Format("{0}\\{1}",AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,"SiteMap.xml"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean the SiteMap Class?

[SiteMap Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sitemap.aspx)

Comment: +1. I looked at the example and it looks weird. It seems like i need to write an XML version by hand? and i use sitemap to read from it? Is that what it does? I am looking for something that i can insert data into and it will tell me if the generated sitemap has reach its limit (i think it was 5k) or if the size reach it limit. Then allows me to save it as an XML sitemap.

Answer (score 2):

[Maybe mine](http://dario-g.com/download.aspx?file=dario_g.Web.SiteMap%5Cdario-g.Web.SiteMap.zip)? :)

Some example of usage and download file you can [find here](http://dario-g.com/projects.aspx). Look for SiteMap Generator section.

Comment: Excellent. I dont see any if statements and i check wikipedia quickly. Will this tell me i hit the 50k limit? Or if the file generated size (after escaping characters and all that) has hit the limit (ignoring the last entry i guess)?

Comment: ahh, no source, its a dll. so i can fix anything if i need to ;). It doesnt look like it tells me when i hit the limit (50k entries/10mb).

Comment: No, it has no limit but 10Mb is enough for common sites.

Comment: You know what, i'll use it. I looked into it and checking the filesize seems more effort then its worth. Your thing doesnt automatically count? i'll just write a counter with it and exist when i hit the 50k. I just hope i dont go over the limit (or forget about the code once i have enough to hit 50k)

Answer (score 0):

When working with ASP.NET, it's necessary to clarify if you are talking about an ASP.NET sitemap (used for site navigation), and a search-engine sitemap.

If you are referring to a search-engine sitemap, check out the article at http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/asp/dynamic-sitemaps-in-asp-net. It presents code for doing what you want.